# CSS Website Sidebar problem

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am making a web project http://conatus.in/alumniconnect/index.php?page=about 
I need to have a floating right sidebar, to accommodate different panels for facebook, news etc.

However, the right sidebar is not working properly. Right sidebar's div id is "sidebarright". CSS is

```
#sidebarright {
float:right;
}
```

The contents are posted just above the main panel `(<div id="content">)`

Left sidebar `<div id="sidebar">` with following css is working good.

```
#sidebar {
float:left;
width:250px;
}
```

I tried several combinations using firebug and dragonfly, but just cant make the right sidebar to properly float.

Comment: how about adding `width:190px`

Comment: i don't think i see a php question anywhere....

Comment: @littlechad tag php removed. I was using this on a php page so inadvertently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used

```
#sidebarright {
float:right;
}
```

When I added more content on the right `div` it `float:right` started working...

Answer (score 0):

Use position:fixed; That makes your sidebar float when you scroll too.

Comment: putting position as absolute is making the whole thing to overlap with the left sidebar

Comment: Put the position as fixed. Not absolute. If that did not work, try to show some example site which has implemented what you wish to accomplish. That will be a lot easier to solve the issue.

Comment: Both of them are not working. Site link is: http://conatus.in/alumniconnect/index.php?page=about

Comment: Try absolute positioning then. See this http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp